# apex:insert name must be literal

Tags: apex, page-template

I have a page template which uses custom controller.
This controller has a property `TabName`. It gets value from component control.
I want to use the value in `TabName` in `<apex:insert name="{!TabName}/>"`, so that it dynamically loads the page with the matching `<apex:define/>` value.

But on compilation I receive `<apex:insert name="#{TabName}"> must be literal` error.

Below is my controller:

```
public with sharing class cls_Home {

    public static String TabName
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public String getTabName()
    {
        return TabName;
    }
}
```

Below is the visualforce page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" Controller="cls_Home">
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <c:cMenu ></c:cMenu>   
        <div class="container">
        <apex:outputtext >Welcome</apex:outputtext>

        <p/>
        <apex:insert name="{!TabName}"></apex:insert> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am using `<apex:composition>` and `<apex:define>`

If I use `<apex:insert name="body"></apex:insert>` instead of `<apex:insert name="{!TabName}"></apex:insert>` everything works fine and I am able to insert below page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false"> 
   <apex:composition template="Home"> 
      <apex:define name="body"> 
         <div class='container'> 
             test
         </div> 
      </apex:define>
   </apex:composition> 
</apex:page>
```

Two pages are using the same composition, but only one will be loaded depending on what tab is selected. Is it possible to use variable name in `<apex:insert name="{!tabName}"/>`
Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2):

`apex:insert` is used to insert parts using `apex:composition` and `apex:define`. See [`apex:insert`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_insert.htm) for more information on how it should be used.

Here's the example from the documents:

```
<!-- Page: composition -->

<!-- This page acts as the template. Create it first, then the page below.  --> 
<apex:page>
    <apex:outputText value="(template) This is before the header"/><br/>
    <apex:insert name="header"/><br/>
    <apex:outputText value="(template) This is between the header and body"/><br/>
    <apex:insert name="body"/>
</apex:page>

<!-- Page: page -->
<apex:page>
    <apex:composition template="composition">
    <apex:define name="header">(page) This is the header of mypage</apex:define>
    <apex:define name="body">(page) This is the body of mypage</apex:define>
    </apex:composition>
</apex:page>
```

Instead, you're trying to the [`apex:include`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_include.htm) function, which literally includes one page inside another (minus tabs, etc, as if it were inline). This feature supports dynamic page includes.

Here's the example code from the docs:

```
<apex:page id="thePage">
    <apex:outputText value="(page) This is the page."/><br/>
    <apex:include pageName="include"/>
</apex:page>

<!-- Page: include -->
<apex:page id="theIncludedPage">
    <apex:outputText value="(include) This is text from another page."/>
</apex:page>
```

There's some oddities with `apex:include`, however, such as you can't use them in `apex:repeat`, and they have to resolve to a valid page or you'll get an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I apologize for not being clear enough to explain my problem. I am using apex:composition and apex:define. If I use <apex:insert name="body"></apex:insert> instead of <apex:insert name="{!TabName}"></apex:insert> everything works fine and I am able to insert below page <apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<apex:composition template="cls_Home">
<apex:define name="body">
<div class='container'>
test
</div>
  </apex:define>
  </apex:composition>
</apex:page>